# Keycloak realm login page rendering issue

Tags: html, css, keycloak, keycloak-services

I have a client protected by Keycloak, when I am redirected to the Keycloak login page, this is how the page is rendered:

[image]

But for the master realm the login page is well rendered:

[image]

Am I missing something?

Comment: did you change the default theme for the realm ? (default is "keycloak", what you see is what you get when you choose the "base" theme). You can set the login theme either for the realm on the realm settings page, or on each client.

Comment: @CédricCouralet Thanks, I didn't know that. I changed the realm settings and the result is much better